# boost asio basic_socket issue

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am a game developer. I encounter this problem when I was developing a chatting feature. My game got crash when running on Iphone and it's caused by basic_socket::close in asio lib. Here is source code:

```
  /// Close the socket.
  /**
   * This function is used to close the socket. Any asynchronous send, receive
   * or connect operations will be cancelled immediately, and will complete
   * with the boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error.
   *
   * @throws boost::system::system_error Thrown on failure. Note that, even if
   * the function indicates an error, the underlying descriptor is closed.
   *
   * @note For portable behaviour with respect to graceful closure of a
   * connected socket, call shutdown() before closing the socket.
   */
  void close()
  {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    this->get_service().close(this->get_implementation(), ec);
    boost::asio::detail::throw_error(ec, "close");
  }
```

so here is my question, why does it always throw a exception? (btw, if you don't use exception feature on boost, the throw_error method will call std::terminate() finally, which will make the program crashed.)

---------------------------update-----------------------------

my game may close the http request and restart it. when it closes the request, it will go here to close the socket. I just don't know why it throws a exception when close, I think it is unnecessary, isn't it?

I have solve the issue which caused by the exception with try & catch. within no-use exception situation in boost, I call std::set_terminate() to avoid crash. So I don't ask for a solution, I ask for why :)

Comment: What was the error message in `ec.message()`?

Comment: @PavelDavydov it may be "close", and it's not the point.

Comment: please include a stack trace where the exception is thrown or a minimally complete example in your question.

Answer (score 1):

[`basic_socket::close()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/close.html) is thin wrapper around the OS specific `::close()` or `::closesocket()` call.  The iOS documentation for [`::close()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/close.2.html) states it will fail if:

> - `[EBADF]` - not a valid, active file descriptor.
> - `[EINTR]` - execution was interrupted by a signal.
> - `[EIO]` - a previously-uncommitted write encountered an input/output error.

Examine the exception or `error_code` to determine the type of failure.

---

As recommended in the Boost.Asio `basic_socket::close()` documentation, one should consider invoking `shutdown()` before closing the socket to obtain portable behavior on graceful closure.  Furthermore, consider using the non-throwing overloads for functions, such as this [`basic_socket::close(ec)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/close/overload2.html) overload:

```cpp
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
boost::system::error_code error;
socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, error);
if (error)
{
  // An error occurred.
}

socket.close(error);
if (error)
{
  // An error occurred.
}
```